# ¿Qué significa Violacion de Segmento?

Tags: c, manejo-de-memoria

Muchas veces uno está programando en **C**, y se encuentra con el mensaje **violación de segmento** o **segmentation fault**, ¿qué significa y por qué se produce?

Comment: Las violaciones de segmento son independientes del lenguaje. Se pueden producir en programas compilados de C, C++, ensamblador, etc. Se pueden producir también en lenguajes interpretados en teoría, aunque es difícil encontrar un lenguaje interpretado sin salvaguardias para accesos fuera de rango y similares. E incluso se podría dar en lenguajes con salvaguardias, pero en ese caso es un error del interprete/compilador y no del programa a ejecutar/interpretar. En cualquier caso un segmentation fault siempre es posible en cualquier programa no trivial. Sugiero bandera independiente-del-lenguaje.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Segmentation fault - violación de segmento.

**¿Qué significa?**

Es un tipo de error en tiempo de ejecución muy común para los programas de 
`C/C++`.

Cuando se ejecuta el programa y el sistema de informes de su sistema lanza una "violación de segmentación", significa que su programa ha intentado acceder a un área de memoria a la cual no le está permitido el acceso. En otras palabras, se trató de acceder a una parte de la memoria que está más allá de los límites que el sistema operativo (Unix GNU/Linux ect) ha asignado para su programa.

**Por qué sucede**

Algunas causas comunes de este problema:

- El uso incorrecto de los operadores `"&"` (dirección/address of) y `"*"`
  (indireccion/dereferencing)
- Cadena de control de formato incorrecto en declaraciones printf o
  scanf

Las cadena de control de formato tienen que tener el mismo número de especificadores de conversión `(%'s)` y de argumentos para ser impresos o leídos, y los especificadores deben coincidir con el tipo de la variable a imprimir o leer. Esto se aplica tanto a fprintf y fscanf como a printf y scanf.

- Olvidarse de usar `"&"` en los argumentos de scanf (este caso es el que menciona Elenasys)

La función scanf toma como argumentos la cadena de control de formato y las direcciones de las variables en las que se van a colocar los datos que se leen (el operador `"&"` se utiliza para suministrar la dirección de una variable). Es común que se olvide de usar `"&"` con cada variable en una llamada a scanf. La omisión de la `"&"` puede causar una violación de segmentación.

- Acceso a más allá de los límites de una matriz/vector o similar: intentar acceder a subíndices de la matriz con un valor menor que el índice de su elemento más bajo o mayor que el índice de su mayor elemento.
- Error al inicializar un puntero antes de acceder a él: Una variable
  "puntero" se debe asignar una dirección válida de la memoria.

  ```
  int *ip;
  std::cout << *ip << std::endl; //usar un puntero no inicializado
  ```
- Tratar de acceder a una parte de la memoria de manera inadecuada aún
  estando accesible para su programa.

  ```
  char *str = "string";// static array de caracteres, sin nombre/id 
                       // este array se crea en modo "read-only memory"
                       // como solo lectura
  str[0]    = 'n';
  ```
- Intentar acceder a un objeto o variable que ha sido borrado de la
  memoria, p.ej.:

  ```
  int *pArrI = new int[9];//solicitamos en el heap 
  delete[] pArrI;         //eliminamos
  std::cout << pArrI[1];  //intentamos acceder a una parte inexistente
  ```

Comment: Gracias por tu excelente explicación

Answer (score 11):

En un sistema Unix con memoria virtual, cada proceso tiene unas regiones de memoria a las que puede acceder. Por ejemplo, en Linux, se pueden ver las Áreas de Memoria Virtual (VMAs) de un proceso leyendo el fichero virtual `/proc/<pid>/maps`:

```
$ cat /proc/self/maps 
08048000-0804c000 r-xp 00000000 03:04 1553592    /bin/cat
0804c000-0804d000 rw-p 00003000 03:04 1553592    /bin/cat
08d7c000-08d9d000 rw-p 08d7c000 00:00 0          [heap]
b7da2000-b7da3000 rw-p b7da2000 00:00 0 
b7da3000-b7eeb000 r-xp 00000000 03:04 2190352    /lib/libc-2.6.1.so
b7eeb000-b7eed000 r--p 00148000 03:04 2190352    /lib/libc-2.6.1.so
b7eed000-b7eee000 rw-p 0014a000 03:04 2190352    /lib/libc-2.6.1.so
b7eee000-b7ef2000 rw-p b7eee000 00:00 0 
b7f14000-b7f15000 r-xp b7f14000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b7f15000-b7f31000 r-xp 00000000 03:04 2190353    /lib/ld-2.6.1.so
b7f31000-b7f32000 r--p 0001b000 03:04 2190353    /lib/ld-2.6.1.so
b7f32000-b7f33000 rw-p 0001c000 03:04 2190353    /lib/ld-2.6.1.so
bfa1d000-bfa32000 rw-p bffeb000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Como se puede ver, se obtiene una lista de regiones de memoria, con permisos asociados (`r` - lectura, `w` - escritura, `x` - ejecución).

Si un proceso intenta acceder a una zona de memoria que no está en la lista anterior, o se intenta un acceso para el que no se tiene permiso, la MMU (Unidad de Gestión de Memoria) del procesador generará una excepción, el kernel tratará esa excepción, consultando la lista anterior, y finalmente, el kernel enviará una señal `SIGSEGV` al proceso.

La acción por defecto para `SIGSEGV` consiste en terminar el proceso generando un volcado de memoria (*core dump*).

Hay otra señal relacionada, `SIGBUS`, que corresponde a error de bus. En algunos procesadores se obtendrá `SIGBUS` si se intenta acceder a una dirección no alineada (por ejemplo, si se intenta acceder a una palabra de 4 bytes situada en una dirección no divisible por 4 bytes). Otra posible causa de `SIGBUS` sería si una de las regiones corresponde a un dispositivo físico mapeado en memoria, y el acceso a esa dirección física falla.

Comment: +1 Interesante respuesta de lo que ocurre en "bajo nivel".

Answer (score 8):

Es un concepto que en forma general sucede cuando:

> Determinado programa intenta acceder a una zona de memoria a la cual
>   no tiene privilegios de acceso.

Buscando una definición en internet se tiene: 
**[Violación de Acceso](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Violaci%C3%B3n_de_acceso).**

> Se define como violación de acceso (violación del segmento o access
>   violation y segmentation fault en Inglés) al intento fallido de acceso
>   a información o a programas a los que no se tiene autorización para
>   ver o modificar. Este mensaje puede ser causado por la configuración
>   de software, por los programadores o por falla de hardware, siendo los
>   más comunes los 2 primeros.
>
> Con los sistemas operativos actuales, cada proceso tiene uno o más
>   segmentos de la memoria del sistema donde puede almacenar y recuperar
>   la información. Cada proceso puede solicitar más o menos memoria
>   (según lo necesitado), y la petición será reconocida por el sistema
>   operativo y comparada con la sección de memoria concedida para el
>   proceso. Generalmente, el proceso que solicitó la memoria es el único
>   que puede leerla o modificarla.
>
> Una violación de acceso ocurre cuando un proceso trata de acceder a
>   una parte de la memoria asignada a otra aplicación, o a una área no
>   usada de la memoria, no teniendo los permisos para hacerlo.
>   Normalmente se produce como resultado de un error de programación, por
>   ejemplo, un puntero descarriado. Otra forma en que podría producirse
>   un "segmentation fault" es con una memoria dañada físicamente, puesto
>   que algún programa escribirá en la memoria, luego intentará acceder a
>   esos datos, pero al tener una falla la memoria, es posible que los
>   datos se hayan borrado, por ende el programa considerará esa dirección
>   de memoria como vacía, o sea no usada, con lo que arrojará el error.

Un ejemplo común de como se puede producir, suponiendo en el siguiente programa omitimos `&` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  int i;
  printf ("introduce tu edad: ");
  scanf ("%d",i);   //genera violación de segmento!
  printf ("Miss Elena, tu edad es: , %d.\n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

en la línea:

```
  scanf ("%d",&i);
```

Entonces se produce una violación de acceso.

Comment: En definición está muy lindo, pero tenés algun ejemplo ?

Comment: Claro @Santi92 edito mi respuesta!

Comment: es una pregunta muy amplia, que una porción de código seguro ayuda a contribuir.

Comment: Vendría bien un ejemplo, en código, Saludos! :)

Comment: Listo @AndresFelipeWilliamsSuarez y Santi92. =)

Comment: Creo que faltaría mencionar aquí por qué el olvido del ampersand genera la violación de segmento...

Answer (score 4):

Una violacion de segmento (segfault) ocurre cuando un proceso intenta acceder memoria que no le pertenece o realizar una operacion para la cual no cuenta con permisos. Ejemplos comúnes son:

1. Intentar acceder una variable que ya fue liberada.
2. Intentar escribir sobre una variable de solo lectura.

Comment: Fabian gracias por responder, no fue aceptada tu revisión ya que usas terminos en spanglish con manejo-de-memory , además es algo muy frecuente en linux el error, por eso es que esta la etiqueta

Comment: Perdon, me turbo apendeje con manejo-de-memory. D: Pero bueno, creo que sí deberia tener manejo-de-memoria como tag.

Comment: @Santi92 las etiquetas deben ser generales, más allá de si un error es común o no, pienso yo.

Comment: @FabiánHerediaMontiel Muchas gracias, ayudemos entre todos a darle calidad al sitio !