# prueba de programa.exe dejo de funcionar

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en el mundo de la programación, apenas estoy comenzando, y resulta que hoy al ejecutar un programa sencillo me salto "prueba del programa.exe ha dejado de funcionar". No entiendo porque me salta esto, nunca me había pasado anteriormente y parece que el problema es precisamente con esta parte del código. alguien me podría explicar que pasa?
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int dia;
    int auxd;
    int contd;

contd=0;
auxd=1;
    do{
        printf("ingrese dia: ");    scanf("%i",dia);

    if(auxd==dia){
        contd++;
        if (contd>4){
            printf(" el dia %i ha pasado las 4 consultas",dia);
        }
    }
    else{
        auxd=dia;
        contd=0;
    }
}while  (dia != 0);
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: cambia a `scanf("%i", &dia);`, scanf espera un puntero.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda :D, no se pq no me salto el error al momento de compilar.

Comment: te recomiendo leer la documentación, y seguramente la IDE que utilizas te debio señalar el error.

Comment: lo tendré en cuenta, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

Como te indican en los comentarios, `scanf` necesita un puntero para poder almacenar los datos introducidos por el usuario. Sin embargo, si etiquetas la pregunta como C++ lo lógico es que pases a usar código C++ y dejes de programar en C.

También sería recomendable que tabulases correctamente el código. Tu programa de menos de 30 líneas ya empieza a ser complicado de leer al estar mal tabulado... cuando tengas que hacer uno de 300 líneas te va a doler, en serio.

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
  int contd = 0;
  int auxd = 0;
  int dia;

  do{
    std::cout << "ingrese dia: ";
    std::cin >> dia;

    if(auxd==dia){
      contd++;

      if (contd>4){
        std::cout << " el dia " << dia << " ha pasado las 4 consultas";
      }
    }
    else{
      auxd=dia;
      contd=0;
    }
  }while (dia != 0);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya se ha indicado en comentarios y en la [respuesta de eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/190018/2742) que el detonante de tu fallo es usar mal la función [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf). Me uno al consejo del resto de usuarios al recomendarte que leas el manual de dicha función; sin embargo saber dónde falla el programa no explica por qué falla. La explicación es algo compleja.

---

La función `scanf` forma parte de las librerías de [c](/questions/tagged/c) y por ello sigue las normas del lenguaje C en su funcionamiento; una de las limitaciones de este lenguaje es la ausencia de referencias<sup>1</sup> y esta limitación hace que para modificar una variable fuera de su ámbito sea necesario pasar la dirección de memoria de la misma.

Dado que has pasado `"%i"` como formato de lectura, la función `scanf` esperará escribir en un entero (`int`) y por ello **asume** que recibirá un puntero a entero. Insisto en el concepto de que **`scanf` asume que recibirá un puntero a entero**, esta función (de las librerías de C) no tiene manera de comprobar que el tipo de dato facilitado coincida con el tipo de dato esperado<sup>2</sup> y por ello asume que lo va a ser; es trabajo del programador asegurar que se cumpla esta [precondición](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precondici%C3%B3n)<sup>3</sup>.

En tu código, fallaste en tu responsabilidad como programador de asegurar la precondición esperada por `scanf`, así que asumió que el entero que estabas pasando como parámetro era un puntero a entero. En tu código podemos ver que no inicializas la variable `dia`, según las normas de inicialización de C++ ésto dejará dicha variable con un valor indeterminado y ese valor será lo que `scanf` interprete como una dirección de memoria que al intentar escribir en ella se producirá una [violación de segmento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/383/2742) y el sistema operativo te informará de que tu *programa.exe ha dejado de funcionar*.

---

1. Puedes conocer la diferencia entre puntero y referencia [en este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/46931/2742).
2. En otras palabras: no puede garantizar [la seguridad de los tipos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_tipos#Chequeo_de_tipificaci%C3%B3n_est%C3%A1tico_y_din%C3%A1mico_en_la_pr%C3%A1ctica).
3. Por estos motivos la función `scanf` se considera como poco segura, propensa a errores y un posible agujero de seguridad en el sistema, incluso existen [tutoriales para sacar provecho de las vulnerabilidades que provoca la función `scanf`](https://dhavalkapil.com/blogs/Buffer-Overflow-Exploit/). Por ello en C++ se desaconseja su uso y en C se aconseja usar alternativas seguras como [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (*`s`ecure `scanf`*).

Comment: Quería centrarme en el por qué falla, no en los demás problemas que tiene la pregunta (indentación, variables no inicializadas, cabeceras inadecuadas) y aún queriendo centrarme, mi respuesta es muy dispersa.

Comment: Si, en ciertos casos es complicado dar una respuesta completa. Por cierto, bienvenido de tu pausa vacacional :)