# Violación de segmento (`core' generado) , ejecutando desde Script

Tags: c, script

tengo esta practica en c:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

void manejador1(int signum);
void manejador2(int signum);
int calculaAleatorios(int min,int max);
pid_t pid_juezPista;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    srand (time(NULL));
    int corredores= atoi(argv[1]);
    int numAle;         
    int *pid_hijos;
    int estado;
    struct sigaction ss;
    struct sigaction ss1;
    pid_hijos = (int*)malloc ( corredores*sizeof(int) );    
    pid_juezPista=fork();

    printf("hola\n");
    if (pid_juezPista==-1){ /* Error en la llamada a fork() */ 
            perror("Error en la llamada a fork()\n"); 
    }
    // codigo del Juez de pista
    else if (pid_juezPista==0) { 
            printf("soy el juez de pista %d\n",pid_juezPista);
        ss.sa_handler=manejador1;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1,&ss,NULL);
        if (-1==sigaction(SIGUSR1,&ss,NULL)){
            perror("error llamada a signation\n");
        }
        printf("soy el juez de pista %d\n",pid_juezPista);
    while(0){
        pause();    
    }
    //codigo del juez principal
    }else{
        sleep(1);
        printf("soy el juez de pista %d\n",pid_juezPista);
        ss1.sa_handler=manejador2;
        sigaction(SIGUSR1,&ss1,NULL);
        sigaction(SIGUSR2,&ss1,NULL);
        if (-1==sigaction(SIGUSR1,&ss,NULL)){
            perror("error llamada a signation\n");
        }
        if (-1==sigaction(SIGUSR2,&ss,NULL)){
            perror("error llamada a signation\n");
        }

        kill(pid_juezPista,SIGUSR1);
        pause();
}

    for(int i =0;i<corredores;i++){  
        pid_t pid_hijos[i]; 
        pid_hijos[i]=fork(); /* Creación de un proceso hijo */ 

        if (pid_hijos[i]==-1) /* Error en la llamada a fork() */ 
                perror("Error en la llamada a fork()\n"); 
        //codigo de los corredores
        else if (pid_hijos[i]==0) { 
                /*hijo*/
            pause();
                break; 
        }else{

        pause();
        }
        printf("soy el hijo %d\n",pid_hijos[i]);
    }
}
void manejador1 (int signum){
    int num ;
    int pistaok=0;
    while(pistaok==0){
    printf("el juez de pista recibe SIGUSR1 y duerme 5 segundos\n");
    sleep(5);
    num = calculaAleatorios(0,1);
    printf("el aleatorio es: %d\n", num);
    if(num==0){
        printf("La pista no esta lista\n");
        kill(getppid(),SIGUSR1);
        pause();
    }
    else if(num==1){
        pistaok=1;
        printf("La pista esta lista\n");
        kill(getppid(),SIGUSR2);
        exit(0);
    }
}
}

void manejador2(int signum){
    if(signum==SIGUSR1){
    printf("El padre recibe SIGUSR1\n");
    sleep(3);
    kill(pid_juezPista,SIGUSR1);
    pause();
    }else if(signum==SIGUSR2){
    printf("El padre recibe SIGUSR2\n");
    printf("la carrera se puede correr\n");
}
}   

int calculaAleatorios(int min, int max) {
return rand() % (max-min+1) + min;
}
```

y ejecuto desde este script:

```
#!/bin/bash



function compila(){
     gcc programa.c -o programa
}

function muestra(){
    cat programa.c
}

function ejecuta(){
    read var1
    ./programa $var1
}

bucle=TRUE
while bucle=true; 
do 
    echo "Por favor, selecciona una opcion de la lista:
    1) Ver.
    2) Compilar.
    3) Ejecutar.
    4) Salir."
    read opcion
    case $opcion in
        1) 
            echo "Elegido opcion 1"
            muestra
            ;;
        2)
            echo "Elegido opcion 2"
            compila
            ;;
        3)
            echo "Elegido opcion 3"
                if [ -f "programa" ];
                then
                    if [ -x "programa" ];
                    then
                    echo "introduzca el numero de corredores:"
                    ejecuta
                    else
                    echo "no tiene permiso de ejecucion"
                    fi
                else
                echo "No existe"
                fi

            ;;

        4) 
            echo "Elegido opcion 4"
            blucle=FALSE
            exit
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Opcion Incorrecta"
            ;;
    esac 
done
```

cuando ejecuto me da este error:

```
Elegido opcion 3
introduzca el numero de corredores:
4
hola
hola
soy el juez de pista 0
soy el juez de pista 0
soy el juez de pista 2190
el juez de pista recibe SIGUSR1 y duerme 5 segundos
el aleatorio es: 1
La pista esta lista
./script1.sh: línea 13:  2189 Violación de segmento  (`core' generado) ./programa $var1
```

Alguien me puede decir porque es, he probado de todo pero no tengo ni idea

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Si no sabes usar un debugger, que veo que desconoces según lo que nos muestras, puedes hacer un rastreo mediante el uso y abuso de `printf`s para ver dónde se queda tu programa colgado. Te aviso: no es una práctica recomendable y te insto a que aprendas a usar un debugger (en tu caso, viendo que usas cabeceras de linux, sería que usases GDB). En cualquier caso, te ayudará a acotar mejor tu problema, ya que se encuentra, sin duda alguna, dentro del código fuente .c

Comment: revisa la funcion `ejecuta()` del script, lo mas probable es que se este quejando por algun acceso que no tienes permitido. Ya hay una pregunta parecida a esta, te dejo el [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383/qu%C3%A9-significa-violacion-de-segmento)