# Que pasa si Sobrepaso el limite declarado de un vector en C

Tags: array, c, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy haciendo pruebas para darle un valor predeterminado a un vector, preguntando al usuario el tamaño del mismo (lo cual es imposible sin usar memoria dinámica, **pero eso no es el caso de la pregunta**).

Mi duda es qué pasa cuando le sigo asignando valores a un vector declarado con cierto tamaño, supongamos 10...  `int vector[10];`, y le asigno un valores en la posicion 11, `vector[11] = 11;`. ¿Dónde se guardan los siguientes valores y por qué no me marca error?

```
int datos[10];
printf("Dame el tamaño del vector... ? : \n");
scanf("%i",&lim);

for(int i = 0; i<lim; i++){
    printf("Dame el valor de la posicion [%i]: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&datos[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Los elementos que se escriben fuera de la posición límite del array `datos[10]`, realmente se están almacenando justo después del espacio de memoria que tiene reservado el propio array. Esto puede provocar dos cosas:

- Que no sobreescriba nada importante en memoria, por lo tanto, se almacenará el valor pero al acceder a esa posición, realmente estarás accediendo a los bytes de espacio de memoria reservado justo después, no al espacio del array
- Que ya exista algo escrito en ese espacio de memoria, por lo tanto, se corromperá el valor almacenado y el resultado en un `printf` será un valor aleatorio, no el esperado.

Probablemente, si continúas sumando números en ese `for`, tu compilador acabará imprimiendo un mensaje de error en tiempo de ejecución: [`Segmentation Fault`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/412/116310).

Si le asignas, por ejemplo, 15 al tamaño de vector, su `output` será el siguiente:

```
Dame el tamaño del vector... ? :                                                                                                                                                     
15                                                                                                                                                                                   
Dame el valor de la posicion [1]: 1                                                                                                                                                  
Dame el valor de la posicion [2]: 1                                                                                                                                                  
Dame el valor de la posicion [3]: 1                                                                                                                                                  
Dame el valor de la posicion [4]: 1                                                                                                                                                  
Dame el valor de la posicion [5]: 1                                                                                                                                                  
Dame el valor de la posicion [6]: 1                                                                                                                                                  
Dame el valor de la posicion [7]: 1                                                                                                                                                  
Dame el valor de la posicion [8]: 1                                                                                                                                                  
Dame el valor de la posicion [9]: 1                                                                                                                                                  
Dame el valor de la posicion [10]: 1                                                                                                                                                 
Dame el valor de la posicion [11]: 1                                                                                                                                                 
Dame el valor de la posicion [12]: 1                                                                                                                                                 
Dame el valor de la posicion [13]: 1                                                                                                                                                 
Dame el valor de la posicion [14]: 1                                                                                                                                                 
Dame el valor de la posicion [15]: 1                                                                                                                                                 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

`Segmentation Fault`, básicamente, se define como un tipo de error causado por acceder a un espacio de memoria que no te pertenece o al que no tienes acceso. Te avisa de que estás haciendo algo mal en tu programa que afecta a la memoria reservada.