# Error al recorrer un archivo con fread (Segmentation Fault) y mostrar un elemento en C

Tags: c, lista, archivo

Tengo que hacer una función que parsee datos de un archivo y los guarden en una lista. Debe ser de un archivo binario así que use `fread` para leer los datos. El 
problema sospecho que sucede recorriendo el archivo leyendo con `fread` y/o con el bucle de `feof`.

```
int parser_EmployeeFromBinary(FILE* pFile , LinkedList* pArrayListEmployee) {
```

//pArrayListEmployee -> Lista principal donde se encuentran los datos

Employee* auxEmployee;// Auxiliar donde se guardan los datos para pasarlos a la lista principal

`if(pFile != NULL && pArrayListEmployee != NULL){

    while(!feof(pFile)){

        fread(&auxEmployee,sizeof(Employee),1,pFile);

        printf("\n%d",auxEmployee->id);

    }

    return retorno;
}`

Para resumirlo, solo quiero mostrar un elemento a modo de prueba pero el programa se corta. Usando el debug , veo que `fread` devuelve 1(OK) en la primera iteracion, pero después marca **Segmentation fault**.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás escribiendo datos sobre memoria que no te pertenece, eso es un [comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) (CI).

Tienes un puntero a empleado:

```
Employee* auxEmployee;
```

Sobre el que lees un **empleado completo**:

```
fread(&auxEmployee,sizeof(Employee),1,pFile);
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- &auxEmployee es de tipo Employee**
```

Aún suponiendo que el tamaño de una instancia de `Employee` fuese igual al tamaño de un puntero a puntero a `Employee`, seguirías teniendo el problema de estar leyendo una estructura sobre un puntero, lo que provoca dicho puntero no esté apuntando a datos (si no que contiene datos de otro tipo) por lo que al des-referenciarlo provocas una violación de segmento]([¿Qué significa Violacion de Segmento?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/383/2742)). No uses el puntero a empleado, usa un empleado:

```
Employee auxEmployee; // <--- Empleado, no puntero a empleado

// ...
// ...
// ...

fread(&auxEmployee,sizeof(Employee),1,pFile);
//    ~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- &auxEmployee es de tipo Employee*
```

---

Tienes un problema adicional, puedes estar leyendo más allá del límite del archivo, vamos a suponer que tienes este archivo:

```
| <-- Inicio del archivo |       Fin del archivo -> |
+------------------------+--------------------------+
| Empleado 1 | Empleado 2 | Empleado 3 | Empleado 4 |
                                       ^
                                       |
```

Tras leer tres empleados, el puntero de lectura está exactamente al final del tercero. Cuando inicias la siguiente vuelta del bucle, la condición para seguir se cumple (`while(!feof(pFile))`) y lees un elemento más dejando el puntero al final del cuarto:

```
| <-- Inicio del archivo |       Fin del archivo -> |
+------------------------+--------------------------+
| Empleado 1 | Empleado 2 | Empleado 3 | Empleado 4 |
                                                    ^
                                                    |
```

El puntero está al final del archivo, pero aún no se reporta final de archivo (EOF), ya que se reporta **después** de intentar leer, así que la condición para seguir se cumple (`while(!feof(pFile))`) e intentas leer un elemento más, según la documentación de [`fread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) (traducción mía):

> Si sucede un error, el valor resultante del puntero de lectura del flujo de datos es indeterminado. Si se lee un elemento parcialmente, su valor es indeterminado.