# Tengo el problema de Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

Ya hice de todo y sigo sin entender que pasa…  la cabecera de las funciones que uso en protocolo2:

protocolo2.h

```
class Protocolo2
{
public:
    char *crea(char *args);
};

char *Protocolo2::crea(char *args) 
{    
    char *mess=args;        
    int tamano = strlen(args);
    char tup;
    int tamano2;
    tup=char(tamano);
    tamano2=tamano+2;
    char mensaje[tamano2];
    strcpy(mensaje,"");
    mensaje[0]='R';
    mensaje[1]=tup;
    strcat(mensaje,mess);

    printf("%s\n",mensaje);
    mess=mensaje;
    return mess;
}
```

El lugar donde lo uso es 
archivo.c

```
#include "Protocolo2.h"

int main()
{
    Trim reco;
    Protocolo2 proto;
    char message[]={"  Ann  "};
    char *mess;
    char *messs;
    char *cadenita;
    mess=reco.recorte(message);         
    strcpy(cadenita,"ESWARAN SHARANYA");
    messs=proto.crea(cadenita);

    return 0;
}
```

El programa originalmente es para un socket, pero estoy probando primero funciones para que corran pero no entiendo que esta pasando.

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando una [formación de tamaño variable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=vla+%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D) (FtV), lo cuál está prohibido en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

```
char mensaje[tamano2];
```

Algunos compiladores aceptan FtVs, pero su funcionamiento no está estandarizado. Las formaciones deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación o debes reservar memoria manualmente.

Además, vas concatenando información en `mensaje` sin variar su tamaño, lo cuál con toda seguridad hace que accedas a zonas de memoria que no pertenecen a la formación y provoca una [violación de segmento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/383/2742).

#### Propuesta.

Ya que estás programando en C++, usa sus herramientas:

```
class Protocolo2
{
public:
    std::string crea(const std::string &args);
};

std::string Protocolo2::crea(const std::string &args)
{    
    std::string mensaje;

    mensaje.push_back('R');
    mensaje.push_back(static_cast<char>(args.length()));
    mensaje.append(args);

    std::cout << mensaje;

    return mensaje;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    Protocolo2 proto;
    auto messs = proto.crea("ESWARAN SHARANYA");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias... eres maravilloso