# Violacion del segmento al usar .clear para vaciar array de strings

Tags: c++

Suponiendo que tengo un array definido de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int Fil=25;
const int Col=20;
typedef array <string,Fil> TFila;
typedef array <TFila,Col> TFila_asiento;
```

y quiero vaciar los strings previamente rellenos a traves del siguiente subprograma:

```
void vacia_asientos(TFila_asiento &asientos){
    for(int fila=0; fila < 25; fila++){
        for(int columna=0; columna<20; columna++){
            asientos[fila][columna].clear();
        }   
    }

}
```

Pero me sale VIOLACION DEL SEGMENTO, ¿como arreglo esto?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa Violacion de Segmento?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383/qu%c3%a9-significa-violacion-de-segmento)

Comment: En mi caso vacia_asientos(TFila_asiento &asientos) accede a posiciones existentes, no deberia salirme violacion del segmento

Comment: Lo tienes del revés. El bucle externo va de `0` a `20`, y el interno de `0` a `25`.

Comment: @Juanjo pero tengo declarada una matriz 25x20 no?, 25 filas por 20 columnas

Comment: Tienes declarado un array de 20 elementos, siendo cada uno de ellos otro array de 25. 20x25. Si fuera un `variable[20][25]` sería intercambiable, pero con tipos *complejos* entra en juego el *padding*. No es lo mismo en tu caso.

Answer (score 1):

Fijémonos en esta parte del código:

```cpp
typedef array <string,Fil> TFila;
typedef array <TFila,Col> TFila_asiento;
```

Si accedo a un miembro de un TFila_asiento:

```cpp
TFila_asiento asientos;
asientos[0]
```

Vas a acceder a un array de tamaño `Fil`, que va a representar las filas. Tienes `Col` elementos para acceder en ese TFila_asiento. Entonces accedes a los datos de la siguiente manera

```cpp
TFila_asiento asientos;
asientos[columna][fila]
```

Pero tu en tu código accedes a los datos de la siguiente manera:

```cpp
asientos[fila][columna].clear();
```

Entonces, cuando la variable `fila` llegue al valor de 20, vas a leer memoria que no es tuya, causando la violación de segmento. La solución es cambiar las filas por las columnas.

**Nota:** Se que no tiene que ver con tu pregunta, pero te recomiendo que le quites los "numeros magicos" de tu código. Ya declaraste arriba las constantes `Fil` y `Col`, así que úsalas en tu código. Si alguna vez tienes que cambiar esos valores vas a tener que buscarlos en tu código, y cambiarlos uno a uno. Si usas las constantes solo lo cambias arriba.

```cpp
void vacia_asientos(TFila_asiento &asientos){
    for(int fila=0; fila < Fil; fila++){
        for(int columna=0; columna<Col; columna++){
            asientos[fila][columna].clear();
        }   
    }

}
```