# sin_titulo.cpp:10:32: error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]

Tags: c++

Estoy intentado hacer que el programa muestre una imagen, pero me sale el ***Error: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]** en la línea 10.

Se que c++ no funciona por si solo con graphics.h así que ya instale la libreria, pero aun así no me funciona.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int gdriver = DETECT ,gmode;
   initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, "");
   readimagefile("sad.jpg",100,100,300,300);
   getch();
   closegraph();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En C++ los literales de cadena tienen de tipo `const char*` porque suelen estar
en areas de solo lectura dentro de la memoria y se prohibe su modificación.

Esta es la firma de initgraph, sacada de la [documentación de BGI](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/cs1300/doc/bgi/initgraph.html):

```
void initgraph(int *graphdriver, int *graphmode, char *pathtodriver);
```

Ahí pathtodriver es un `char*` (una cadena modificable), así que al pasarle
`""` (una cadena de longitud 0, constante) el compilador se queja. Si lo
permitiera, initgraph podría intentar modificar la cadena constante y
podriamos obtener [una violación de segmento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383/qu%C3%A9-significa-violacion-de-segmento).

Si sabemos (o confiamos) que initgraph no va a modificar pathtodriver podemos
castear la cadena constante a una cadena modificable con const_cast:

```
initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, const_cast<char *>(""));
```

Si no confiamos en initgraph, otra opción es crear un arreglo de caracteres
a partir de la cadena constante, y pasarsela a initgraph:

```
char pathtodriver[] = "";
initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, pathtodriver);
```

Tambien, en la documentación de initgraph dice que se le puede pasar nullptr
(o NULL) como el valor de pathtodriver. En ese caso, usa el directorio en el
que se encuentra para buscar los archivos del driver:

```
initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, nullptr);
```